# How to hide a higher node in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I want to create a diagram on `tikz-qtree` that look something like this:

[image]

Where "alt", "a", and "s" are aligned at the base, and "R", "AF", and "AF" are also aligned at the base (note that I removed the last edge before the leaves; I need it this way).

My first attempt aligned "s" with the higher node (its sister node):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=base},
    frontier/.style={distance from root=80pt}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \Tree
        [.Adj
            [.Adj
                [.alt\\R-Adj ]
                [.a\\AF-G ] ]
            [.s\\AF-N ] ]

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Then I tried adding another node before "s" to make "s" be a sister of "alt" and "a". However, The line between the top "Adj" and "s" is broken and doesn't look elegant.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=base},
    frontier/.style={distance from root=80pt}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \Tree
        [.Adj
            [.Adj
                [.alt\\R ]
                [.a\\AF ] ]
        [.\node[shape=coordinate] {};  %removes the space (gap) between the edges 
            [.s\\AF ] ]]

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding my issue, I have two questions: (1) how can I set my code so that the right-most line goes straight from "Alt" to "s" without the break in between while still keeping "alt", "a", and "s" aligned at the base? And (2), how can I make the edges (ie, the lines) below each "Adj" be the same length without changing to `anchor=north`? Changing the `anchor` to `north` misaligns my nodes because the letter "l" is taller than "a" and "s" in the sister nodes.

Answer (score 2):

With `forest` package is simple (for me, since I'm a bit more familiar with it than with `tikz-qtree`) :

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes styles
       align = center,
        font = \linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
   inner sep = 1pt,
% tree style
parent anchor = south,
 child anchor = north,
if n={1}{l sep=3mm,s sep=1mm}{l sep=6mm, s sep=4mm}
            
                }
%
[Adj
    [Adj,
        [alt\\R]
        [a\\AF, tier=L2]
    ]
    [s\\AF,  tier=L2]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**

or would rather have the next tree with edges fixed angles  and without nodes on the top of tree.

**Edit (2):**

Original example using `standalone` document class is now adopted to ˙beamer`. By this is show, that image is independent from used document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Tree drawn by \texttt{forest} package}
\center
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes styles
       align = center,
        font = \linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
   inner sep = 1pt,
% tree with fixed angles of edges
      calign = fixed edge angles,
calign angle = 30,       
                }
%
[,coordinate
    [Adj,
        [alt\\R]
        [a\\AF, tier=L]
    ]
    [s\\AF,  tier=L]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
If you prefer (for some reason) to use `tikz-qtree` package to drawn your trees and willing to do manual adjustment for nodes positioning, than you may consider the following solution which to some degree simplified defining levels distances at nodes positioning:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newlength{\LD}
                        

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlength\LD{7mm}
\tikzset{
          nodes = {inner sep=2pt, align=center,anchor=base},
frontier/.style = {distance from root=3*\LD},
 level distance = \LD
        }
\Tree   [.~
            [.Adj
                [.alt R ]
                [.a AF  ] 
            ]
            [.\node[yshift=-\LD] {s}; AF ] 
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I've never used `forest`. But this looks neat. What does `tier=L2` do here?

Comment: @Ernesto,   with `tier`  marked nodes it vertical align them regardless in which levels of tree they are,  In this particular case are aligned nodes  `a\\R`  which is at tree bottom level (l*level 2*) with `s\\N` which is written in the middle level. (*level 1*). The top level is *level 0*.

Comment: @Ernesto, see edited answer (a bit improved design of trees). BTW,  did any of suggested solution fulfil your expectations?  Or you still wait on `tikz-qtree` solution?

Comment: thanks for your explanation! Unfortunately, `forest` didn't work for me. As a standalone file, I replicated the tree. In my beamer file, I was able to see the text but not the edges of the tree. I believe it may have some conflict with a different package or something. I did, however, find a solution through `tikz-qtree`, which I added below.

Comment: @Ernesto, my code examples works in `bemaer` presentations too. Tested.   See edited last example in answer, which now use `beamer` document class.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with the code, I discovered that the code I had been using works; I simply had to move the `tikzset{}` portion from the preamble to inside the `tikzpicture` environment. I don't know why having these settings in the environment works but not when they're in the preamble, but it did. Below is my "new" code and the output. I've added this solution in case it's helpful to others.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=base},
            frontier/.style={distance from root=80pt}}
        
        \Tree
        [.Adj
            [.Adj
                {alt\\ R}
                {a\\ AF}
            ]
            {s\\ AF}
        ]
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your claims are false. Your code also works if `\tizset` is before `tikzpicture` or even in document preamble. The cause of your problems is somewhere else, Where, is hard to say, since your document structure and preamble is unknown to us. I suspect that in preamble (or in document) you have  many of them, where the last one overwrite the previous  ones.